# Roblox plugin: How do I redirect the plugin user to a certain website?

Tags: plugins, roblox, luau

I am currently making a Roblox plugin and I have created a help button. However, I want to redirect users to a webpage (let's say, [example.com](https://example.com/)). Through all of the API pages that I browsed through, I could not find anything. Is it possible to do so? And if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of January 2023, this is not a supported use case for developers.

There are a number of adjacent features that are close but really don't work for what you're going for :

- The `plugin` object has a function to [OpenWikiPage()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Plugin#OpenWikiPage) but this is only for internal documentation.
- [HttpService](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/HttpService)
  is unable to launch any non-http protocols, so you cannot use it to
  launch an external program either.
- GuiService has a deprecated, internal function [OpenBrowserWindow()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/GuiService#OpenBrowserWindow), but only CoreScripts can use that.
- There's now a BrowserService with the function [OpenBrowserWindow()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BrowserService#OpenBrowserWindow), but similar to GuiService, this is only for internal use.

The only workaround I could imagine would be to fetch the contents of the page and display it in a TextLabel, which supports [Rich Text](https://create.roblox.com/docs/building-and-visuals/ui/rich-text).